# new tab not loading the URL in internet explorer using selenium and python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, python-3.x, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to open 2 tabs in IE( IE 11) using selenium webdriver and python(3.4).

here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Ie()
#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
time.sleep(3)
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_after)
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')

time.sleep(3)
```

Now this code is working fine in chrome. but in IE it opens new tab but doesn't load the stackoverflow URL.

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\new_tab.py", line 12, in <module>
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What is wrong?